# Preserving build folder when using actions/checkout@v2

Tags: next.js, github-actions

I have a GitHub self-hosted runner set up to deploy a Next.js app that checkouts the repository, builds and restarts pm2.

The thing is whenever the `actions/checkout@v2` step kicks in, it deletes all the files within the repository including the build folder `.next` that contains all the build files. This leads to the downtime of the application whenever the workflow runs.

I went through the source code of `actions/checkout@v2`, at the time of asking this question, [in this file](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/main/src/git-directory-helper.ts) starting at line #109, the logic for deleting the contents of the directory is written. If my understanding is correct, I must have set up git-lfs to prevent the deletion of files. I have no need for git-lfs as of now.

I can submit a pull request to have a config which prevents the deletion of files within the directory. Am I missing something? Is there any workaround for this issue?

My current workflow file for more clarity,

```
name: Build & Deploy
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash -l {0}

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
     # This action deletes all my build files when it runs
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          clean: false

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Deploy
        run: pm2 restart myApp || pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- start
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is fixed. Seems the config `clean: false` doesn't work the first time. More information is available in this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/430#issuecomment-764445919).

Comment: Nice! But it seems that it have (almost) 1seg of downtime. Is possible to show user a page, for example, 'Website in maintenance' or anything? At least to dont show 'Error Browser (unable to process requests)' to user